# How to modify the auto-formatting rule in vscode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

The VS Code allows the `shift`+`alt`+`F` formatting. However, the formatting style in VS Code for R codes is not always satisfactory (E.g., sometimes you may want to use `if {...} else {...}` as an one-line expression rather than a code block, but VS Code always chooses the latter).

Is there a way to modify the specific rules for the auto-formatting?

Answer (score 2):

The way to customize the formatting style is to add the following code in your `~/.Rprofile`:

```r
options(languageserver.formatting_style = function(options) {
  styler::tidyverse_style(scope = "indention", indent_by = options$tabSize)
})
```

where `indent_by` must be used as above for the styler to know the document indention from vscode.

Read https://styler.r-lib.org/reference/tidyverse_style.html for more details about how to customize the styling.